# Kotlin to Java, Bottom Navigation Bar

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I am currently watching some tutorials on youtube about how to add a bottom navigation to my super simple app. I got to the last part where the transitioning between fragments occurs and he wrote it in Kotlin and I have not studied that at all. How could I write this in Java? Im guessing it is somewhat similar but I am newish to java as well so I am sorry if this sounds really stupid.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val fragment_weekly = FirstFragment()
        val fragment_biweekly = SecondFragment()
        val fragment_monthly = ThirdFragment()

        setCurrentFragment(fragment_weekly)

        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
            when(it.itemID) {
                R.id.weekly -> setCurrentFragment(fragment_weekly)
                R.id.biweekly -> setCurrentFragment(fragment_biweekly)
                R.id.monthly -> setCurrentFragment(fragment_monthly)
            }
            true
        }


}

    private fun setCurrentFragment(fragment: Fragment) =
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().apply {
            replace(R.id.flFragment, fragment)
            commit()
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Fragment fragment_weekly = new FirstFragment();
    final Fragment fragment_biweekly = new SecondFragment();
    final Fragment fragment_monthly = new ThirdFragment();

    setCurrentFragment(fragment_weekly);

    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(
            new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
                    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.weekly: {
                            setCurrentFragment(fragment_weekly);
                            break;
                        }
                        case R.id.biweekly: {
                            setCurrentFragment(fragment_biweekly);
                            break;
                        }
                        case R.id.monthly: {
                            setCurrentFragment(fragment_monthly);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
}

private void setCurrentFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.flFragment, fragment)
            .commit();
}
```

Comment: `setContentView` `BottomNavigationView` `getSupportFragmentManager()` is all showing as cannot resolve... any ideas why this would be?